# What do you call it when a story gives a warning to the reader?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing an analysis of quotation from The Handmaid's Tale. In the story, the author puts in an anecdote of an interview of a Nazi soldier's wife. I comparing that to Offred's recent meeting with the Commander. It seems like Atwood brought up that memory to serve as a warning to Offred (But she doesn't notice why that memory is triggered).

Question: What do you call it when a story gives a warning to the character(s) in the novel?

Comment: Are you asking about a warning to the reader (as in the title) or a warning to the characters (as in the body of your question)? *Foreshadowing* works for the first but not for the second.

Comment: To the character @PeterShor

Comment: Such an anecdote might serve as *a hint*, *a prompt* or *a trigger*. A related word is *a spoiler*, meaning information that gives away essential parts of a developing (literary or movie) plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a story gives a warning of a plot turn, it is called **foreshadowing**.

> Foreshadow -- To present an indication or a suggestion of beforehand; presage: hostilities that *foreshadowed* all-out war. - [American Heritage Dictionary, 5th Ed.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foreshadow)

Comment: *Foreshadowing* is the right answer. But a bomb that is shown to the audience but not to the characters could not be a [*MacGuffin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin), although it might be a [*Chekhov's gun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chekhov's_gun). A *MacGuffin* is something lacking intrinsic importance that drives the characters' actions. For example, a bomb might be a MacGuffin if the characters are trying to find a bomb that somebody has hidden at a school, but the story is really about the relationships of the people they encounter while doing so.

Comment: Why this was accepted I am unsure.  Foreshadowing alerts the reader.  The OP is asking what it is called when events alert a character.  I would instead  say this is just that, a warning.  If you need a 5-cent word, then maybe omen or portent.

Answer (score -1):

It's called a cautionary tale. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cautionary_tale#:%7E:text=A%20cautionary%20tale%20is%20a,is%20said%20to%20be%20dangerous.) defines it thus:

> A **cautionary tale** is a tale told in folklore, to warn its listener of a danger. There are three essential parts to a cautionary tale, though they can be introduced in a large variety of ways.
>
> First, a taboo or prohibition is stated: some act, location, or thing is said to be dangerous. Then, the narrative itself is told: someone disregarded the warning and performed the forbidden act. Finally, the violator comes to an unpleasant fate, which is frequently related inexpansive and grisly detail.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. That's presumably because it lacks detail. If you look at answers around the site, we have an expectation that answers will contain a sourced definition and/or an explanation of _why_ the suggested answer is correct.

Comment: Hi, welcome to our site. You may not be aware that we're quite different from other Q&A sites: rather than inviting personal opinions, we're looking for *detailed, authoritative answers* supported by evidence (preferably linked to the published source). For further guidance, see [answer] and take our **EL&U site [Tour]**. :-)